# jQuery UI $.datepicker.noWeekends not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using the followng script:

```
<script>
    $( function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            altField: "#alternate",
            altFormat: "DD, d MM, yy"
        });
    } );

    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am using the following HTML:

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker">&nbsp;<input type="text" id="alternate" size="30"></p>
```

The problem is that all the weekends still show. Any help on what I should do will be appreciated.

In case needed this is the 'Head' code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

You're declaring two datepickers on the same element and the second overrides the first. Combine your code to:

```
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    altField: "#alternate",
    altFormat: "DD, d MM, yy",
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
  });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/z71b4gob/)**

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You state that while using the `noWeekends` utility function, "*The problem is that all the weekends still **show**.*"

Per the [documentation for $.datepicker.noWeekends](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-noWeekends), this utility function does not control whether or not weekends are visible in the calendar. Rather, it controls whether or not a weekend date is *selectable*.

As given in [another good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42251842#answer-42251921), however, you also need to combine your code blocks.

Comment: Thanks for the help.